# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Assignment...'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

> Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Assignment_20539BEAE4B141780E3B2D295A6858EAA8B5E9C0AD25E8A54154D0AB1E7DFA28' to type 'AssignmentSystem.Models.AssignmentViewModel'.

I have mvc application with the following model classes

```
/// class for generating EF CodeFirst Db

public class Assignment
{
    public Int64 AssignmentId { get; set; }


    public Int64? ApplicationUserId { get; set; }


    public string Text { get; set; }


    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }


    public virtual List<User> Coordinators { get; set; }


    public virtual List<User> Executors { get; set; }


    public virtual List<User> DelayResponsible { get; set; }

    ....
    ....
}

/// this class for interaction with view
public class AssignmentViewModel : Assignment
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AvaliableUsers { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AvaliableExecutors { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AvaliableCoordinators { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> SelectedUsers { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> SelectedExecutors { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> SelectedCoordinators { get; set; }


    public AssignmentViewModel() : base ()
    {
        AvaliableUsers = new List<SelectListItem>();
        AvaliableExecutors = new List<SelectListItem>();
        AvaliableCoordinators = new List<SelectListItem>();

        SelectedUsers = new List<string>();
        SelectedExecutors = new List<string>();
        SelectedCoordinators = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

My application worked perfectly, but after certain moment (just recompile) POOOF! It doesn't work.

I get the error mentioned above in code:

```
// GET: /Assignment/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(long? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        AssignmentViewModel assignment = (AssignmentViewModel)db.Assignments.Include(a => a.Attachments)
            .Include(a => a.Coordinators)
            .Include(a => a.DelayResponsible)
            .Include(a => a.Executors)
            .Include(a => a.MemberComments)
            .Include(a => a.Initiator).First<Assignment>(f => f.AssignmentId == id); //here
        ....
        ....
    }
```

And this:

```
AssignmentViewModel assignV = new AssignmentViewModel();
Assignment assignment = new Assignment();
assignV = (AssignmentViewModel) assignment;
```

Doesn't work also;

I tried to clear VS 2013 temp files [as it written here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/86201dcf-7de2-40b8-bd71-3f6527ca105c/unable-to-cast-object-of-type-x-to-type-x)
Also tried to rebuilt from scratch in another directory whole solution.
Tried [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/psheriff/archive/2011/11/08/clean-up-after-visual-studio.aspx)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is trying to cast an `Assignment` object (in the first exception, it's actually a dynamic proxy object that inherits from `Assigment`) to an `AssignmentViewModel`. Because `AssignmentViewModel` inherits from `Assignment`, it's trying to downcast a less specific type to a more specific type; and that's not possible.

Look into using something like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) to map your model to a view model.